# Make a variable set inside a module global

Tags: python, module, global-variables

I know there are a lot of questions asking how to use a pre-defined global variable in a module, but I want to do the opposite--I want to take a variable defined inside a module and make it global.  Here's the code:

```
import badobjectmask as bm

bm.getgoodlist(datalen = 13501, listname = list2)
print(ra)
```

with the module code for badobjectmask being

```
global goodlist
global ra

def getgoodlist(datalen, listname):
    for f in range(1):
        for n in range(datalen):
            if (data5[n]['COADD_OBJECT_ID'] in set(listname)) == False:
                fcngoodlist.append(data5[n])
                fcnra.append(data5[n]['RA'])
    goodlist = fcngoodlist
    ra = fcnra
```

I've tried getting rid of the `global` bit and instead ending with

```
    return
    goodlist = fcngoodlist
    ra = fcnra
```

and have tried putting the `global` bit inside the function as well.  With all of these strategies, I get the error `NameError: name 'ra' is not defined`, which I assume is because the `ra` variable isn't being made global.  How do I fix this?

Comment: I would just define the variables ra and goodlist in the scope of the `badobjectmask.py`. Then you can import then via `from badobjectmask import ra, goodlist`. I wouldn't like to just have them appear as a side effect. It's like when you say: `from sys import path`. That `path` variable is assigned inside the `sys` module and you can import it.

Comment: @Dr.V: Importing variables doesn't work the way it would need to work for that to be a good idea. Importing variables copies their current values into the importing namespace (and throws an error if there are no values yet).

Comment: It only really makes sense for constants, or at least things that aren't supposed to be reassigned.

Comment: @celery: This seems more like a job for return values than for globals.